# Redux state is not updating even it is updated in the action but not in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, redux, react-redux

**The State Is Not Updating But It is changed in action**

This Is my Code For main.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
const initialState = false;
const NavReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "NAVIGATION":
      return state = action.data
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const mainReducer = combineReducers({
  NavReducer,
});

export default mainReducer;
```

And Here is my action

```
// 
// In My Case The Data Will be in formatt of true or false
// data = true or false

// 


export const Navigation = (data) => {
  return {
    type: "SWITCH",
    data: data,
  };
};
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-toastify": "^8.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Before clicking the button
[The State Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL4Fv.png)

[The Action Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LWzc.png)

After CLicking The button
[No Change In the state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeXhs.png)
[But In The Action The Data Is Changed But The state is not changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxwMF.png)

**I am Sure That Stack Overflow community Will solve the problem**

Comment: I think you are using diffrent type 'SWITCH' for which you have not created any case in the reducer.

Comment: in addition to what @pankajchaturvedi said, the `"true"` in the last screenshot you shared looks like it's coming through as a string, not a boolean, which may or may not be a problem depending on how you're using it

Comment: Ya @pankajchaturvedi yes you are right thank you. i used the name of reducer in the case not the name of action. Thanks. The Last line of this question is true- Stackoverflow community always help